# Form value store in two place

Tags: forms

i want to store single from data in two places i.e http://www.abc.com/post.php and http://www.xyz.com/post.php. how can i do this. please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use jQuery to post the form. On a button click, use [jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit the form twice.

Erick